# Java MicroService needs to access postgres table without exposing data via endpoint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Looking for recommended mechanism where Java MicroService needs to access postgress table. No need to expose this data via endpoint.

1. MVC style access uses repo, entity and controller (Springboot framework)
2. write function to connect DB and perform SELECT calls

Is it possible to combine 1(skip controller) & 2 ?
Please advice

Comment: yes to your first Q.  I still need to connect and query DB from my MS so thread does not help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1** (with skipping controller): perfectly fine. You still need to query the db and process the result. And most of the time this is the easiest with JPA and spring repositories.

**Question 2**: perfectly fine

**Combine 1 & 2**: It is possible of course. When you have entities and repositories, you can still use native select calls if you need for some specific functionality (probably because of the complexity of the queries). Have a look at spring jdbctemplate: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate